Why is 1+2+3 = (1+2)+3
Not sure if this is a stupid question, apologize if it is.
I am curious why we can add the first 2 numbers, then add the third one when doing addition of 3 numbers.
There is a similar (IMHO) question, but for the union operation of sets, Set theory : is union of more than two sets possible, it mentions that there is the axiom of union that makes the whole thing possible, I am looking for something similar but for numbers

Associative property: sum is defined for two numbers. Then we prove that $(1+2)+3= 1+(2+3)$ and thus we are free to remove paretheses without ambiguity.

@MauroALLEGRANZA Hi, thanks for your reply, associative property indeed comes to my attention, but in my understanding, it is more like (1+2)+3 = 1+(2+3), I am curious why we can remove the paretheses "we are free to remove paretheses without ambiguity"

Oh, I get it! With the associative property, we know that no matter where the parenthesis (necessary considering sum is a  binary operation) is, it won't affect the result, then we can remove it

FYI, an interesting "picture proof" for associativity of multiplication is given on p. 13 of A Text Book of Algebra by William Steadman Aldis (1887).

@DaveL.Renfro Thanks for showing me this! I will check it out! :)

It's because if you have three piles of beans and you gather up two piles and put them in a bag, and then put in the third pile, you end with the same number of beans in the bag as if you had swept all three piles into the bag at one time.
